# Sublime Text replace characters and variable numbers

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm new to SublimeText. I'm trying to replace

```
Thing_001:
```

with emptiness. However

```
001
```

changes and goes to 002, 009, 888, etc. What's the easiest way to do this? I haven't had much luck with Regex so far.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file looks like:

```
Thing_001: foo bar blah
Thing_548: foo bar blah
Thing_991: foo bar blah
Thing_008: foo bar blah
Thing_024: foo bar blah
Thing_069: foo bar blah
Thing_357: foo bar blah
Thing_999: foo bar blah
```

use the following regex:

```
Thing_\d{3}:
```

in the `Find What:` field (make sure the regex search option is selected). Don't put anything in the `Replace With:` field.

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/sY5qY8/1)